# Apply a lemma to a conjunction branch without splitting in coq

Tags: logic, coq, coq-tactic, formal-verification

I have a conjunction, let's abstract it as: `A /\ B` and I have a Lemma proven that `C -> A` and I wish to get as a result the goal `C /\ B`. Is this possible?

If yes, I'd be interested in how to do it. If I use split and then apply the lemma to the first subgoal, I can't reassemble the two resulting subgoals `C` and `B` to `C /\ B` - or can I? Also `apply` does not seem to be applyable to only one branch of a conjunction.

If no, please explain to me why this is not possible :-)

Comment: Are you trying to prove `C /\ B` from the knowledge of `A /\ B` and `C -> A` alone? This won't be possible as the proposition `A /\ B -> (C -> A) -> C /\ B` is not true in general (take `A = B = True` and `C = False`).

Comment: @SvenWilliamson No, they're trying to prove `A /\ B` from `C /\ B` and `C -> A`. They don't "have `A /\ B`", they "have *goal* `A /\ B`", and they want to get "goal `C /\ B`" with the help of a lemma `C -> A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could introduce a lemma like :

```
Theorem cut: forall (A B C: Prop), C /\ B -> (C -> A) -> A /\ B.
Proof.
  intros; destruct H; split; try apply H0; assumption.
Qed.
```

And then define a tactic like :

```
Ltac apply_left lemma := eapply cut; [ | apply lemma].
```

As an example, you could do stuff like :

```
Theorem test: forall (m n:nat),  n <= m -> max n m = m /\ min n m = n.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply_left max_r.
  ...
Qed.
```

In this case, the context goes from :

```
Nat.max n m = m /\ Nat.min n m = n
```

to

```
n <= m /\ Nat.min n m = n
```

I assume that's what you are looking for.
Hope this will help you !